# How to find the 'm' oldest forks of a repository using GitHub api

Tags: javascript, github, repository, github-api

I need to obtain the 'm' oldest forks of a given repository, using the GitHub API. To get the 'm' oldest forks I'm trying to obtain the forks sorted from oldest to newest.

Taking the example of "it-cert-automation-practice" repository of google, I've tried the following APIs:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/google/it-cert-automation-practice/forks?q=sort:created_at
```

```
https://api.github.com/repos/google/it-cert-automation-practice/forks?q=sort:oldest
```

```
https://api.github.com/repos/google/it-cert-automation-practice/forks?q=sort:updated_at&fork:true&order:asc
```

```
https://api.github.com/repos/google/it-cert-automation-practice/forks?q=sort:created_at&fork:true&order:asc
```

Comment: I'm not sure GitHub record the "age of a fork" (whatever that would be) in the first place, but if they do, you'll definitely need to use a GitHub-specific interface to get it, since Git itself only has clone, not fork.

Comment: GitHub api does have a created_at field which can tell when a fork was created, I'm trying to sort using this 'created_at' field. I'm not very experienced in git and github can you explain it a bit what do you mean by github specific interface.

Comment: The GItHub API is a GitHub-specific interface. Using `git clone` to copy a Git repository from GitHub is not a GItHub-specific interface as it works with any Git implementation (go-git, jgit, and so on). It doesn't look to me like GitHub offer a way to sort by arbitrary fields though: all I can find here is https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/sorting-search-results which seems to be specific to commits or issues, not repositories.

Comment: Here's a sample result, when we set an organisation, let's say google and set the number of repos and forks, under any result displayed if we click on the view button of forkers, we can see the oldest forkers, I'm trying to achieve this.

https://shubham1206agra.github.io/github-orgs-explorer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [List forks endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-forks), take into account the following:

- Use **sort** parameter with value **oldest**
- If you want to list more than 100 repositories, you will need to handle pagination using the **page** parameter.

See a working example using Octokit for getting the oldest 40 forks of Node.js repository.

| Get oldest forks of GitHub repository | [<kbd>View in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-71056572) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const owner = 'nodejs';
const repo = 'node';
const repoInfo = await github.request(`GET /repos/${owner}/${repo}`, {
  owner,
  repo,
});

const {forks_count} = repoInfo.data;

// By default it will return 30 results, you can get up to 100 using per_page parameter.
const searchResult = await github.rest.repos.listForks({
  owner,
  repo,
  sort: 'oldest',
  per_page: 40
});

console.log(searchResult.data.map(repo => `${repo.full_name} created at ${repo.created_at}`), `Found ${searchResult.data.length} of ${forks_count} total forks for ${owner}/${repo} repository`);
```